# Animation - Zoom in & out animation of image while swiping a layout left to right in android

Tags: android

**I haven't worked on animation. Can anyone let me know how to zoom in & zoom out a image when we swipe it from left or right using vertical layout in android.**

The above animation exist in ***ios.***

I can able to swipe linear layout left and right but need some animation while moving the image (inside linear layout) from left to right.

> Animation should be like, if the left image moved to center then the
>   image should be zoomed in/look bigger and vice versa to right image.
>   left & right image should be zoomed out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the transition APIs.
https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/

or if all the layouts that you want to animate are part of the same activity then you should go with the property animation APIs
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation

This is a sample zoom animation
https://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom

Have fun, hope I've been of some help